# Global request/response interceptor

Tags: servicestack

What would be the easiest way to setup a request/response interceptor in ServiceStack that would execute for a particular service?

A request filter (`IHasRequestFilter`) works fine but a response filter (`IHasResponseFilter`) is not triggered if the service returns non 2xx status code. I need to retrieve the status code returned by the method as well as the response DTO (if any).

A custom ServiceRunner and overriding the `OnBeforeExecute` and `OnAfterExecute` methods seems to work fine but I find it pretty intrusive as the service runner need to be replaced for the entire application and I couldn't find a way clean way to isolate per functionality the tasks that need to be executed in those methods.

Is there some extension point in ServiceStack that I am missing that would allow me to execute some code before each service method and after each service method? A plugin would be ideal but how can I subscribe to some fictitious `BeforeExecute` and `AfterExecute` methods that would allow me to run some custom code?

---

UPDATE:

Just after posting the question I found out that global response filters are executed no matter what status code is returned by the service which is exactly what I needed. So one last question: Is it possible to retrieve the service type that will handle the request in a request filter? I need to check whether this service is decorated by some custom marker attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out a solution to my question about how to retrieve the service type in a custom request/response filter:

```
appHost.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
    var metadata = EndpointHost.Metadata;
    Type serviceType = metadata.GetServiceTypeByRequest(requestDto.GetType());

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was just in the middle answering a Q pointing you to metadata :) Also you can also view the metadata ServiceStack has with the [/operations/metadata](http://razor.servicestack.net/operations/metadata) route.

Answer (score 3):

> A custom ServiceRunner and overriding the OnBeforeExecute and OnAfterExecute methods seems to work fine but I find it pretty intrusive as the service runner need to be replaced for the entire application

Quick note, you can opt-in and choose only what requests should use a custom service runner, e.g:

```
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(
  ActionContext actionContext)
{           
    return useCustomRunner(actionContext.RequestType)
      ? new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext)
      : base.CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(actionContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IHttpRequest has OperationName. I think thats what you are after.

Comment: No, that's not what I am after. I need the service type (`System.Type`) so that I can read any possible custom attributes that this service might have been decorated with. I have already found a solution and will post it as answer.